# Remove, hide or Change Alpha of a UIView from another UIViewController not responding? iOS

Tags: ios, methods, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

I'm having problem to access a UIView from a different UIViewController. 
As I read, you can easily access a method inside a class by simply calling it this way. 
From a ViewController called, AViewController I'm calling:

```
ProfileViewController *ChangeAvatar = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
[ChangeAvatar ChangingAvatar:image];
```

So in my ProfileViewController I have a method declared in .h/.m like

```
-(void)ChangingAvatar:(UIImage *)image {

  NSLog(@"Changing AVATAR!"); //This executes so I see it in console

  [avatarView removeFromSuperview]; //This code seems not to work
  [avatarView setHidden:YES]; //This code seems not to work neither
  avatarView.alpha = 0.0f; //This code seems not to work neither

//I tried adding but didn't work. Like: 
  imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
  imgView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-100, self.view.bounds.size.height/2-150, 200, 200);
  imgView.image = image;

  [self.view addSubview:imgView];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgView];

}
```

So my question is, how is this possible that I can execute a NSLog, but not I can not remove,hide or change alpha from ProfileViewController.view? Any idea?

Comment: Assuming at the point you create the `ProfileViewController` and invoke its `ChangingAvatar` method that the avatar is already visible on the device, the wrong instance of `ProfileViewController` is being used. You need to get the instance that is already being presented. In your case above, you will find that `avatarView` is `nil`.

Comment: So how can I get the instance that is already being presented?

Comment: Need to see more code to be able to answer. Need to see at least where the presented `ProfileViewController` is created and presented.